# Using semantic-ui in webpack project

Tags: webpack, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the `semantic-ui-less` package, but whenever I try to import one of the .less files, I get an error saying that `../../theme.config` can't be found. Of course, I have a `theme.config`, but it can't find it.

The .less file that's importing theme.config is located in `node_modules/semantic-ui-less/src/definitions/modules/checkbox.less`. With a relative path of ../.., I would expect it to want themes.config to be in `node_modules/semantic-ui-less/src`, but obviously I can't put my own theme.config inside of an installed node module directory - so where can I locate it so that less will be able to find it? Or is there some configuration I can pass to less-loader that will tell it how to find it?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly point webpack to your `theme.config` file with [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) option:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'theme.config': path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'theme.config')
  }
}
```

And of course you need a loader for `.config` files.

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and it's not working for me, I still get: `Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../theme.config in /home/talin/Projects/web/react-semantic-demo/node_modules/semantic-ui-less/definitions/modules`

Here's what I added to the webpack config:

`resolve: {
  alias: [
    { '../../theme.config': path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'theme.config') }
  ]
},`

Comment: Also, I think there's an error in your example, according to the webpack docs alias takes a map, not an array - however, I tried it both ways and no effect.

Comment: You're right, its must be object. Try set key to `theme.config`

Comment: I've done some more experiments and looked at the code to less-loader. As far as I can determine, @import statements from within .less files don't go through the webpack resolver. To test this, I added a NormalModuleReplacementPlugin with a callback that logs the requested path to the console, and I see my .less files in the output, but not the .config file.

Comment: Did you add `theme.config` to less loader `test` regexp? `test: /(\.less|theme\.config)$/`

Answer (score 0):

I use the solution provided in [Artem Butusov's tutorial](https://www.artembutusov.com/webpack-semantic-ui/).

It solves the problem by running a `postinstall` script that fixes the wrong references in the *semantic-ui-less* package by overwriting the `theme.config` in *node_modules* with the one you provide.

It also fixes the wrong font paths in the themes.

(I came across this solution in an [issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-LESS/issues/6) of *semantic-ui-less* when I was trying to solve this same problem.)